# .Net Core Cookie Authentication Not Working When hosted in IIS

Tags: asp.net, angular, iis, .net-core

When running the application standalone (just kestrel server running on a specified port in my case :3001) I can login (creating an auth cookie) and use my session without issue to make subsequent calls to my API controllers. However once I publish the application to host via IIS I can login without issue but all subsequent request to my API controllers fail authorization and redirect to login.

To demonstrate my issue I have stripped my application down to a working sample that can be found here: [Angular2AspNetCoreStarter](https://github.com/wickdninja/Angular2AspNetCoreStarter)

To reproduce:

1. clone the repo
2. navigate into project directory `cd Angular2AspNetCoreStarter`
3. install dependencies `dotnet restore` & `npm install`
4. build `npm run build`
5. publish `dotnet publish`
6. Host via IIS [Publishing to IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis)
7. Navigate to hosted site (in my case it was @ `http://localhost/ng2starter`)
8. Login with any username/password
9. Open side navigation
10. Click Send Anonymous Ping (notice it works! I used [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to inspect traffic)
11. Click Send Ping (notice the 401 and redirect to login)

I've inspected the logs and the error I find in the kestrel logs is :
`CookieAuth was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed`
FYI 'CookieAuth' is the scheme's name which I defined in the appsettings.json file.

Comment: @WarrenP did you run `npm install` and build using `npm run build`

Comment: Your new instructions are much better! I got it to work. I'll test it on IIS when I'm at home and see if I can figure it out.  Of course, running in IIS makes it harder to debug.

Comment: Agreed... that's half my problem lol If only you could run in IIS and attach the debugger like in ASP.NET (not core)

Comment: That's actually a good secondary question. How can I attach to a dotnet core process inside IIS + ANCM? I have tried and so far it seems, I can't.

Comment: AFAIK since IIS is simply a reverse proxy to the kestrel process debugging the IIS process wouldn't provide any good information. However attaching a debugger to the kestrel process should be possible and I would expect that to be a useful venture.

Comment: To debug your app on IIS you can attach your debugger to the *w3wp* process

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the problem might be left over or overlapping cookies from a different "localhost" application with the same cookie name.   I ran your sample in IIS and was getting the same 401 error from the ping and then noticed in chrome a bunch of localhost cookies with that same default name

.AspNetCore.CookieAuth

I cleared out all of the cookies and then ran your sample again and got back a "PONG"

The cookies that get created when you're using IISEXPRESS
localhost:PORT

will also come down when you're running in IIS with just localhost, so my guess is that the IISEXPRESS cookies are being sent to the IIS instance and since you have ephemeral data protection they aren't going to be able to decrypt.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly my problem.

Comment: How exactly did you move the cookies?

Comment: Usually in the configuration for the authentication you can "name" the cookie. So probably here https://github.com/wickdninja/Angular2AspNetCoreStarter/blob/master/Startup.cs#L104

Comment: To check quickly without removing the cookies, just use your browser's private mode, incognito mode or whatever name it has.